# Is there such a thing as an automatic build in any IDE for .NET?

Tags: .net, ide, build

I'm not talking about a continuous build process, but the excellent feature in Eclipse whereby any java code changes are automatically built in a background thread. With this enabled, running unit tests or applications is immediate. Going back to the 'manual' builds of VS20XX is quite painful.

I've only seen this working in Eclipse for java code - does anything like this exist for .NET languages, in any IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in Visual Studio - one of the best features in Visual Basic that is not in C# is that Visual Basic is compiled in the background as you work.  Though, I'm not sure if it speeds up your unit tests, etc.

You might look into using TestDriven.NET, you can right click and execute a single unit test very quickly in most cases, and it will only compile what is needed to execute the unit test.

Comment: I like the sound of that (I use resharper, which does something similar, but that does a build of your project prior to running). Will give it a go - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use msbuild in some background process, periodically building your solution, but this would yield to file locking issues and generally would be a crappy solution. 
Why not set up say CruiseControl.NET? it's not complicated, doesn't need any source control (could use filesystem) and basic setup for a project is very simple.

Comment: doesn't cc.net use msbuild anyway?
It's an interesting idea, but doing a full build whenever anything changes sounds a bit of overkill - or have I got the wrong idea?

Comment: msbuild can be instructed to only build those parts that have been changed.

Comment: isn't that what the standard VS incremental build does anyway? When you have big solutions, it takes a tooth-grindingly long time even when it determines that there's no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Cruise Control: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/ It does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: He said that he is not looking for a continuous build process.